# Lexical Pasting Text with \n programmatically

Tags: reactjs, lexicaljs

I have a text that a get from my database that comes stringfied and contains the \n characters for new lines.

For instance: " I'm in the first line here. **\n** I'm in the second line here "

How do I make this text to be loaded into the editor taking in consideration the new line character?

Thank you